# Limit rpois distribution?

Tags: r

I'm looking to use `rpois` but I'm having trouble with the lower limits erroring my model.

A toy example:

```
a <- 1
repeat{
if (a >= 1) {
  x <- rpois(a, 1 * .15)
} else {
  x <- 0
}
  print(x)
  if (a - x < 0){
   break
  }
}
```

Basically, I can't have `a - x` be negative. Is there a way to set a min/max limit on `rpois`?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `extraDistr::rtpois`? It's for the truncated Poisson where you can set the truncation bounds.

Comment: Otherwise, you could set a comparison condition on your sample value and re-sample if the value(s) is outside of your bounds. It might be helpful to add a bit more about your problem/what you're trying to do because there may be a better way.

Comment: `extraDistr::rtpois` is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have found a solution in `extraDistr::rtpois`

This would have worked as a base R alternative:

```
rlimpois <- function(n, lambda, lowlimit, toplimit){
  sample(x=lowlimit:toplimit, size=n, 
         prob=dpois(lowlimit:toplimit, lambda), replace=TRUE)
}
```

so for example for a sample sized 20 from a Poisson distribution with parameter 2 where none of the values exceed 3 might be

```
set.seed(1)
rlimpois(20, 2, 0, 3)
# 1 2 2 0 1 0 0 3 2 1 1 1 3 2 3 2 3 0 2 3
```